# Apache POI Date format partially working

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using poi 3.8 to create excel sheet

I have some date columns which I am formitting with the below code

```
CreationHelper ch = wb.getCreationHelper();
short df = ch.createDataFormat().getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(df);
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setDataFormat(df);

Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    cell.setCellValue( sdf.parse("04/30/2013") );
    sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

but the problem is that poi is not formating some of the date cells, instead of showing date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format it is showing date as number value like 451235

One more thing to mention here is that I am using pre created styles with setDataFormat(df) method call for date and default format for non-date columns

Comment: Have to check: Did you call `setCellStyle` on the `Cell` that needs to be formatted as a date?

Comment: If you read the formatting rules for the cell back using POI, does POI see the correct formatting?

Comment: One thing that I have observed so far is that poi does not apply format if Date cell is aligned e.g if cellStyle.setAlignment is called on cell cellStyle.setDataFormat is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `.setCellStyle(...)` are not additive. That is, if you apply a Date format style:

`cell.setCellStyle(cs);`

and then apply some other style:

`cell.setCellStyle(thickBorderStyle)`

you will be removing your date format