# Apache POI setting date format not always properly formatting in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xls

I've been working with Apache POI lately to export to XLS. I'm trying to export dates with proper formatting. For this, I use the following code:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
);

cell.setCellValue(exportDate.getDate());

cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

// To check that this row is properly formatted
log.info("Format of row " + rowIndex + " and cell " + cellIndex + ": " + DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell));
```

The problem is that in the beginning, Apache POI is exporting this date correctly, but after approximately 20 times exporting a date, it will not be formatted anymore. I've checked at the end of the creation of the workbook if everything is still a date format with `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)` and every call returned `true`.

Does anyone know what's happening? [There is a related question from 5 years ago but unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992496/apache-poi-date-format-partially-working).

Could this be some weird behavior from Excel?

Comment: Are you sure you are not modifying cellStyle anywhere else in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when i was trying to modify cell's style, this problem appears when you exceed a certain number of instances of the class CellStyle.
I solved this problem by using the same object for all of the cells witch require the same style. Here is an example of a class that i have created to solve the problem:

```
package com.h2s.service.utils;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;


public class ExcelCellStyle {

    private HSSFCellStyle defaultCellStyle = null;
    private Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> mapColoredStyles = new HashMap<>();
    private HSSFWorkbook workBook = null;
    private HSSFCellStyle defaultCellStyleForTitle = null;
    private HSSFCellStyle defaultCellStyleForBigTitle = null;
    private HSSFFont bigFont;

    private ExcelCellStyle(){
    }

    public static ExcelCellStyle getInstance(){
        return new ExcelCellStyle();
    }

    public HSSFCellStyle getDefaultCellStyle() {
        if(defaultCellStyle == null){
            generateDefaultStyle();
        }
        return defaultCellStyle;
    }

    private void generateDefaultStyle() {
        defaultCellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    }

    public HSSFCellStyle getColoredCellStyle(short index) {
        if(!mapColoredStyles.containsKey(index)){
            HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
            newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(index);
            newCellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            mapColoredStyles.put((int) index, newCellStyle);
        }
        return mapColoredStyles.get((int)index);
    }

    public void setWorkBook(HSSFWorkbook wb) {
        this.workBook  = wb;
    }

    public HSSFCellStyle getDefaultCellStyleForTitle() {
        if(defaultCellStyleForTitle == null){
            defaultCellStyleForTitle = workBook.createCellStyle();
            defaultCellStyleForTitle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForTitle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForTitle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForTitle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
        }
        return defaultCellStyleForTitle;
    }

    public HSSFCellStyle getDefaultCellStyleForBigTitle() {
        if(defaultCellStyleForBigTitle == null){
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle = workBook.createCellStyle();
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setFont(getBigFont());
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            defaultCellStyleForBigTitle.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        }
        return defaultCellStyleForBigTitle;
    }

    private HSSFFont getBigFont() {
        if(bigFont == null){
            bigFont = workBook.createFont();
            bigFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 28);
            bigFont.setFontName("Calibri");
        }
        return bigFont;
    }
}
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

The input from everybody so far helped to get the solution. I'm not sure how this could be the problem, but what helped was by creating the CellStyle once and then use the same style for different cells. Before I dynamically created the rows and cells which created a new CellStyle every time. I've noticed no difference between using workbook.getCreationHelper() and workbook.createDataFormat().

Comment: "I'm not sure how this could be the problem": There are [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=2007): "Unique cell formats/cell styles". In `Excel` `*.xls` the limit is only 4,000 different combinations of cell formats. So if you are creating a cell format for each cell, this fails after 4,000 cells.

Comment: @AxelRichter If I remember it correctly ' if the issue is about number of styles reached the maximum limit' then it always throw an exception. I wonder why Mauro Palsgraaf did not get any exception

Answer (score 2):

@Mauro Palsgraaf  I used to set the date stye for both XSSF and HSSF and I never faced a problem.
I use similar code as explained by XtremeBaumer

```
workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
style = workbook.createCellStyle()
style.setDataFormat(dateFormat);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

The only difference I can notice in your code is that you use creationHelper to createDataFormat but I use the workbook.I am not sure whether this is really an issue but may be you can try using the Workbook

```
createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was resolved by creating the cell style once at the beginning of the workbook instead of every time I needed it. Not sure though why this fixes it.

Comment: @MauroPalsgraaf can you accept it as answer sothat other people knows this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This code is for `XSSFWorkbook` so I am not sure if it will fit you 100%.

```
short dateStyle = workBook.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-mm-yyyy;@");
XSSFCellStyle dateCellFormat = workBook.createCellStyle();
dateCellFormat.setDataFormat(dateStyle);
cell.setCellStyle(dateCellFormat);
```

For `XSSF` it works perfectly fine. Maybe it has to be reworked for `HSSF`